# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter for plumber

Tags: c#, inheritance

```
using System;

namespace lab4
{
    class Lab4
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Prompt.prompt();
        }
    }
}

public class CommissionEmployee
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get;}
    public string SSN { get;}
    private decimal grossSales;
    private decimal commissionRate;




        public CommissionEmployee( string firstName, string lastName, string ssn, decimal grossSales, decimal commissionRate)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        GrossSales = grossSales;
        CommissionRate = commissionRate;//might be wrong


    }

    public decimal GrossSales
    {
        get
        {
            return grossSales;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value),
                value, $"{nameof(GrossSales)} must be >=0");
            }


            grossSales = value;
        }
    }

    public decimal CommissionRate
    {
        get
        {
            return commissionRate;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value <=0 || value >=1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value),
                value, $"{nameof(CommissionRate)} must be > 0 and <1");
            }
            grossSales = value;
        }



    }

    public virtual decimal Earnings() => CommissionRate * GrossSales;



}


public class Plumber : CommissionEmployee
{

    private string custName;
    private string Location;

    public Plumber(string firstName, string lastName, string ssn, decimal grossSales, decimal commissionRate, string custName, string location) :
         base (firstName, lastName, ssn, grossSales, commissionRate)
    {

        custName = CustName;
        Location = location;

    }

    public string CustName
    {
        get
        {
            return custName;
        }
        set
        {
            CustName = value;
        }
    }
    public string location
    {
        get
        {
            return Location;
        }
        set
        {
            location = value;
        }
    }



    public override decimal Earnings() => GrossSales * CommissionRate;

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"Name: {FirstName} {LastName}/n" +
        $"Social Security Number: {SSN}/n" +
        $"Sales: {GrossSales}/n" +
        $"Rate of Commission: {CommissionRate}/n" +
        $"Customer Name: {CustName}/n" +
        $"Location of Service: {Location}/n" +
        $"Earnings: {Earnings()}/n";



}

public class Prompt
{

    public static void prompt()
    {

        Plumber Plumber1 = new Plumber();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the plumber's first name: ");
        string first = Console.ReadLine();
        Plumber1.CustName = first;


    }
}
```

}

It won't allow me to create a new Plumber object without filling in the parameters. However, the assignment is trying to get me to prompt the user to enter those properties. It won't let me use empty parameters.Error CS7036

Comment: You have to choose between two options: fix `Plumber` class so that it has a parameterless constructor like you're trying to call, or stop trying to call a parameterless constructor that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
Plumber Plumber1 = new Plumber();
```

This is calling a default constructor but your Plumber class does not have a default constructor (no parameters).  The only constructor in Plumber is the overloaded constructor:

```
 public Plumber(string firstName, string lastName, string ssn, decimal grossSales, decimal commissionRate, string custName, string location) :
```

If you want to do this you would need to add a default constructor to Plumber, but Plumber inherits from CommissionEmployee which only has a non-default constructor, so as it exists now any constructor of Plumber would have to call the non-default constructor of the base class CommissionEmployee.  So you may want to add a default constructor to CommisionEmployee:

```
public CommissionEmployee() {}
...
public Plumber() : base() {}
```